# Insert foreign key reference in entity frameowrk 3.5

Tags: c#, .net, frameworks, entity

I have 3 tables
 a. Employee (EmpID (pk), EmpName)
 b. Department (DepID (pk), DepName)
 c. EmployeeDepartmentMapping (ID (pk), EmpID(fk), DepID(fk))

When I am inserting new employee, I want to insert correspoding Emp-Dep mappings in the EmployeeDepartmentMapping table using entity framework 3.5. Can any body help/tell me how to insert many-many relationships using entity framework in database?

Thanks,
Ashwani

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Employee emp = new Employee();

EmployeeDepartmentMapping edm = new EmployeeDepartmentMapping();
edm.Emp = emp;
```

if u know the dept id.
then

```
edm.Dept = _ent.Department.where(i => i.deptId == dept_id).first();

_ent.AddToEmplyee(emp);
_ent.AddToEmployeeDepartmentMapping(edm);
```

Comment: Thanks Franklins, it worked. I want one more favor. Can u tell me how to update foreign key reference. Suppose I have a table which stores employee and its role mapping where roles is coming from different table. Now I want to change the role of the employee. The new table has employeeId and RoleId as foreign keys. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

```
emp.<RolesEmpMapTable>Refernce.Load();
emp.<RolesEmpMapTable>.Role = _ent.Roles.where(i=>i.roleId == role_id).first();
```